# Explicit cochain for Shapiro's lemma with trivial coefficients

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, induced-representations

(cross-post from stack exchange after not receiving any answers)

I'm wondering the following: if we have a finite-index subgroup $H\subset G$, and a cocycle $[c]\in H^1(H,\mathbb{Z})$, is there any way to get an explicit cochain representing its image under the isomorphism $H^1(H,\mathbb{Z})\to H^1(G, \hom(G/H,\mathbb{Z}))$? Maybe if we pick an explicit set of representatives for $G/H$ there's some canonical choice?

Something similar was asked previously [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306063/description-of-shapiro-lemma-by-cochain), but didn't receive an answer, and the given reference to Neukirch didn't explain how "picking a transversal" worked.

Comment: I think if c is a homomorphism from H to Z and T is a transversal then the corresponding cocycle takes g in G to the mapping sending tH to c(h) where gt=t'h with t,t' in the transversal and h in H.   But possibly it is c(h^{-1})

Comment: The linked question provides and answer "See Cohomology of Number Fields, (1.6.4). " See also : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259123/concrete-formula-for-shapiros-lemma